# List tags that exists in a playbook

Tags: ansible, ansible-playbook

I have a play that runs one or more roles.  I would like to list available tags without parsing all the code.  I am indeed experimenting some difficulties in remembering all the tags I put during developing phase..

How can I list all the tags in the tags properties :

```
- name: "Any Task"
  tags:
   - debug

- name: "any second taks"
  tags: 
   - second
```

I would like a command that gives

```
debug
second
```

Comment: I appologize, I did not manage to read well the '--help' section of 'ansible-playbook'

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can list all tags using CLI option `--list-tags`.

Example playbook:

```
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: false
  tasks:
    - name: "Any Task"
      debug:
        msg: 'any msg'
      tags:
       - debug

    - name: "any second task"
      debug:
        msg: 'any second msg'
      tags:
       - second
```

Run: `ansible-playbook test.yml --list-tags`

Output:

```
playbook: test.yml

  play #1 (localhost): localhost    TAGS: []
      TASK TAGS: [debug, second]
```